# How to automatically multiple match/dropdown on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am trying to generate a report for the assets within the company. I am essentially trying to create an automatic drop down list. I have done some research on using `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` methods but I cannot seem to get it right.

What I would ultimately like to make, is a report where you enter the specific group in the green cell. All of the members for that group will be generated below the green cell.

Essentially, the data that I have looks like cells D:G. The type of dropdown list I would like to make is in cells I:J.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Sample screenshot]

EDIT: FORMULA

=INDEX($F$2:$G$17,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($F$2:$F$17=$I$2)/($F$2:$F$17=$I$2)*ROW($F$2:$F$17))-ROW($F$1), ROWS($H$3:H3)))

Comment: Why don't you [edit] your post to include the INDEX/AGGREGATE formula that you tried so we can help you and show you where you went wrong?

Comment: @jeeped sorry, please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15, MATCH(0, IF($E$2=$B$2:$B$15,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$2:E2, $A$2:$A$15), 0, 0),""), 0)), "")}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]